# If $u:\cup_t \Omega_t \times \{t\} \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable, is $\tilde u:\Omega_0\times (0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, bochner-spaces

For each $t \in [0,T]$, let $\Omega_t$ be a bounded open domain. There is a diffeomorphism of class $C^2$ $$F_t:\Omega_0 \to \Omega_t$$
that maps the domains. Assume that that $F_t$ is differentiable wrt. $t$ (the intention is that $\Omega_0$ evolves in a smooth way without jumps).

Define $Q=\bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Omega_t\times \{t\}$. We can put the Lebesgue measure on $Q$ if we think of $Q$ as a non cylindrical domain.

Given $u:Q \to \mathbb{R}$, define $\tilde u:\Omega_0 \times(0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$\tilde u(x,t) = u(F_t(x), t).$$

> My question is, given $u \in L^p(Q)$, is $\tilde u \in L^p(\Omega_0 \times (0,T))$?
>
> And conversely, given a function $\tilde u \in L^p(\Omega_0 \times (0,T))$, is $u \in L^p(Q)$, where $u(x,t) :=\tilde u(F_t^{-1}(x),t)$?

**The only issue I have is with measurability. Assume that the integrals are all finite. I just need to know whether the functions are measurable**.

See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791569/uncountable-disjoint-union-of-measure-spaces/791663?noredirect=1#791663) for more details about the disjoint union, and [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791454/is-this-composition-of-functions-lebesgue-measurable) for one step of the problem.

Note that I am using the equivalence between $L^p(0,T;\Omega_0)$ and $L^p(0,T;L^p(\Omega_0)$ here (for $p \neq \infty$).

Comment: What measure are you putting on Q?

Comment: @NateEldredge I guess the product Lebesgue measure on the non-cylindrical domain $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (here $\Omega(t) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$)?? Whatever the natural one may be.